# Why do we need to typecast the WebDriver instance to JavascriptExecutor before calling the executeScript method?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, inheritance

`JavascriptExecutor` is an interface which provides some default code for `executeScript` method.

`RemoteWebDriver` implements this interface and overrides the method like this:

```
@Override
    public Object executeScript(String script, Object... args) {...}
```

When we create an instance of WebDriver we use an instance like FireFoxDriver or ChromeDriver. These methods will inherit the parent method `executeScript`.

Yet, whenever we want to call executeScript we never call this method directly from the driver object like this:

```
driver.executeScript(...)
```

Instead, we always typecast it to the interface first and then call it.

Here's a sample code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor executor =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("window.location.href = 'https://google.com';");
```

Why do we need to typecast driver to `JavascriptExecutor`? Why can't we just call `driver.executeScript` instead? Alternatively, could we typecast it into RemoteWebDriver instead?

Comment: What do you mean "parent methods"? `WebDriver` does not extend `JavaScriptExecutor`. And what do you mean by "not defined in this interface"? [It's right there.](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/latest/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The implementation is done by the RemoteWebDriver class. But that still doesn't change the fact that we're typecasting a ChromeDriver / FireFox Driver to a parent type.

Comment: See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397713/why-we-need-to-cast-chromedriver-object-to-javascriptexecutor-object

Comment: basically the type (an interface is basically a type) of webdriver doesn't guarantee the javascriptexecutor method... some drivers may not actually implement it. (though I can't think of one that doesn't... maybe appium or winium drivers?)

Comment: @pcalkins It shouldn't matter whether a child class implements it or not (like `appium`). This interface has already been implemented by the parent `RemoteWebDriver` which means that this method is visible to the child instance. I don't see any reason why we're constantly typecasting before calling the interface method.

Comment: yeah, this might be more of a legacy thing... but since you've already casted to WebDriver, it's not known to be available until you typecast.  If you are only using a single driver in your code you could just cast to FirefoxDriver from the start. (actually you wouldn't be casting at that point, just keeping the type as FirefoxDriver...)  The architecture will probably change as more drivers conform to the W3C standard.

Comment: @pcalkins Your answer is correct. Would you mind putting that as an answer to this question? I think that this is answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are typecasting because out code is usually using the webdriver type, which is an interface and does not include the executeScript method.

When you pass the driver around as "webdriver" type, the classes assume it only has the WebDriver interface's methods. You could also cast it to Chromedriver type, but that same code would not work for Geckodriver, or other types.

Credits to pcalkins for this answer.

Hence, you cast it to an interface JavascriptExecutor in order to keep the code generic so that it will work with Geckodriver / Chromedriver etc. Alternatively, you could also cast it to RemoteWebDriver and it would still work. But it's more readable when casted to JavascriptExecutor.

Here's an architecture diagram that explains this perfectly. Credits to qacult.com for this image.

[image: hierarchy of Selenium classes]